# setTextDirection Programatically in api level 17

Tags: android, android-edittext

We are  trying to set textDirection "**rtl**" programatically.

But, when we set it to "**ltr**" then on button click changing textDirection to "**rtl**" is not working.

Here is my code :

```
     edtUSername.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_LTR);

     btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    edtUSername.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL);
                }
            });
```

And this is not working only in api level 17.

Comment: try calling edtUSername.invalidate() post setting direction

Comment: @harsh Parikh : try this  edtUSername.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL);

Comment: @dex : not working that as well

Comment: Is the button's width set to `wrap_content` or `match_parent` ?